# Parse.com Slow Queries Analytics - Query with empty where-clause

Tags: parse-platform

my backend is made with parse.com Now I experienced in the Parse.com Analytics-Section the Tab "Slow Queries". Nice feature to see how your queries are performing.

Now what I see there is that there are queries of mine with empty where clauses you can see it here:

```
Users   where:{ facebookID: ... }

Friends where:{ user: ... }

Friends where:{ objectId: ... }

Users   where:{}

Friends_Rel where:{ friend: ..., user: ... }

Friends_Rel where:{}
```

Now my question is why are there empty where clauses? Because I assume that this Query results in an error and it is not wanted by me I think.
I always build my queries either like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Friends_Rel");
query.equalTo("friend", friendID);
query.equalTo("user", userID);
query.find({
    success: function(results) {

    },
    error: function(error) {

    }
});
```

or like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Users");
query.get(objectID, { // Gets row you're trying to update
    success: function(row) {

    },
    error: function(row, error) {

    }
});
```

Is there any explanation for this clauses where they could come from? Does the .get Method results in where:{}? I am not sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing as sunsetting parse.com